# How can I display the text in pre tag in the default fonts that html uses?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am developing an AngularJS application.
In that, when I fetch data from the database to display it to the user, the extra spaces are trimmed to one space from the data which has more than one space between two words.

I tried `<pre>` tag of HTML and it works fine except one thing. It changes the style of the text. I applied different CSS in `<pre>` tag but I'm not getting the convenient result.

So how can I make it look like as it looks in normal HTML?

I'm attaching a sample:

`<pre style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14px">{{name}}</pre>`

It's working but it just doesn't help with the styles.

Comment: what do you want it to look like?

Comment: Try to use `<p ng-bind-html="name"></p>`

Comment: Thank you friends, Sajin's answer helped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
<p style='white-space: pre;'>
```

instead of `pre` tag

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped. I applied ur solution and also added "margin: auto" and it looks perfect.